# How to Find Frame with lower dimension for $C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let ${f_k}$ be a frame for $C^n$ with unit norm and frame lower bound A>1. Let I(index set) be subset of {1,2,...,m} such that $|I|<A$, where $m$ is the dimension of the  frame.
then ${f_k}$ where $k\notin I$ is a frame for $C^n$ with frame bound A-|I|.

Can any one suggest how to proceed to prove above statement?

Comment: You have made a statement. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: I edited it.I am not getting how to proceed to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

$I\subset${1,2,...m} and $|I|<A$(lower frame bound) and A>1.

$ A \|f\|^2 \leq \sum\nolimits_{ k\in I}|<f,f_k>|^2+\sum\nolimits_{ k\notin I}|<f,f_k>|^2\leq B\|f\|^2 $  .

By Schwartz inequality,

$ A \|f\|^2 \leq |I|\|f\|^2+\sum\nolimits_{ k\notin I}|<f,f_k>|^2\leq B\|f\|^2 $  . since {$f_k$} where k=1...,m are unit norm vectros.